Interpreting cross table summary
I am generating a simple 2 by N contingency table that summarizes women’s employment status before and during/after COVID-19. The columns represent the two time periods: 1) Before COVID and 2) During/After COVID.
The employment status summaries are as follows:
Employment Status            Before COVID   During/After COVID
Missing Response                      41%              18.6%
Unemployed (Homemaker)          301 (8.8%)          443 (20%)
Employed                      1315 (49.9%)       1276 (61.4%)

The data shows an increase in both the percentage of unemployed homemakers (from 8.8% before COVID to 20% during/after COVID) and the percentage of employed women (from 49.9% to 61.4%). This seems counterintuitive since we would expect the rise in unemployment to coincide with a drop in employment.
How do I interpret these results ? Any suggestions is highly appreciated. Thanks.

The first problem is that the percentages are wrong... If 301 is 8.8% of the grand total, that would mean a total of ~3420 subjects. But if 1315 is 49.9% of the grand total, that gives a total of ~2635 subjects.
Also, in the 2nd column, the percentages do not add to 100%...
The 2nd issue is that you are looking at the percentages, not the counts. The counts should be entered in a cross table (aka contingency table). Your first row is only the proportions? Why? And then any statistics is done on the counts, normalized to the marginal totals.
Last, for after Covid, you have a large drop in no-response; that skews both of the proportions below (they both need to go up to absorb this drop; hence we should look at counts only...). Btw, try just a 2x2 contingency table, and see if you can now interpret it? That should clear the confusion.
